# Redirect to Index page after session timeout not working in .war

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

We are using Struts2 & GWT-EXT.

We have crated a LoginInterceptor which will be called before performing certain restricted tasks.

Here is the method of LoginInterceptor

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation arg0) throws Exception {

        try
        {
            System.err.println("inside the login interceptor");
            Map session = arg0.getInvocationContext().getSession();
            User loggedInUser = (User)session.get("loggedInUser");

            if(loggedInUser != null)
            {

                return arg0.invoke();
            }else {

                throw new AuthorizationException("unAuthorized");               
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {          
            throw e;
        }       
    }
```

After session timout.. If a user clicks on any button. Before proceeding LoginInterceptor gets called and checks whethere user is logged in or not.

In the code

We have a method  `public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {`

where i check that

```
if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {
        if (caught instanceof StatusCodeException
                && caught.getMessage().contains(
                    "<title>Error 500 unAuthorized</title>")) {
            MessageBox.alert("Session Expired", "Session has been expired. Press Ok to redirect to Login page.", new AlertCallback(){ 
                    public void execute(){ 
                        History.newItem(HistoryToken.INDEX_PAGE.toString());
                    } 
                }); 

        } else if (caught.getMessage().contains("LoginInterceptor")) {
            History.newItem(HistoryToken.INDEX_PAGE.toString(), true);
        }
```

Then, I redirect it to Index Page.

This works in Eclipse fine in Hosted Mode but when I create .war and run it in JBoss. It does not comes into `onFailure` method and gets redirected directly to Index Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiii...

try this code just before the invocation exception code. before `if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {`
 condition....

```
if(caught.getMessage().contains("unAuthorized") )
    {
        MessageBox.alert("Session Expired", "Session has been expired. Press Ok to redirect to Login page.", new AlertCallback(){ 
            public void execute(){ 
                History.newItem(HistoryToken.INDEX_PAGE.toString());
            } 
        }); 

    }
```

Comment: Hey Friend... Thanks for the suggestion. How could i have not tried it ? You have saved my ass.. Thanks again